# Using Chi-Squared to minimize error between model and observed

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, minimization, chi-squared

I am doing a project on fitting observed rotational velocities (which change based on distances) in a galaxy via a couple of models
In my code, I am plotting some observed data vs a model. This model consists of a formula that can be manipulated via 2 fixing parameters: `r0` and `p0`. Basically, I need to find the values of these two fixing parameters that will minimize the space between the observed graph and the model graph. My aim is to minimize Chi-Squared, which is `((v_obs - v_model)/error)^2`, and then graph my model.

I created an array of the integrals and v_model (in my code it's named "function") based off the distance (r, which is also an array). So via this code, I get an array of v_model at each distance. `am` is the amount of measurements (in this case, 21)

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize as opt
import numpy as np

def integrand(r,p0,r0):
    return (p0 * r0**3)/((r+r0)*((r**2)+(r0**2)))*4*3.1415926535*r**2
integrals = []
for i in r:
     integrals.append(quad(integrand, 0 ,i,args=(p0,r0)))


#function --> v_model
functions = []


for x in range (0,am):
    k = integrals[x][0]
    i = r[x]
    functions.append(np.sqrt((4.302*10**(-6)*k)/i))
```

Since the error changes for each data point, I made that an array as well.
I'm a little bit lost on where to start, but I've created this so far for minimizing based off of examples online or on stackoverflow. I choose initial guesses for p0 and r0.

```
def chisqfunc(p02,r02):
    model = np.sqrt((4.302*10**(-6)*((p02 * r02**3)/((r+r02)*((r**2)+(r02**2)))*4*3.1415926535*r**2))/r)
    chisq = numpy.sum(((v_obs-model)/errors)**2)
    return chisq

x0 = np.array([p0,r0])

result = opt.minimize(chisqfunc,x0)
print (result)
assert result.success == True
```

With executing this, I get the error :

```
'function' object has no attribute 'minimize'
```

I have two main questions: How do I fix this error and how do you minimize when your data is in an array?

Comment: So what is `opt`? I think I already reminded you of [mcve].

Comment: Are you working with latest observational data? JLA, PLANCK15?

Comment: In my previous project if it is not compulsory, I used data file and I opened in python program and then with for loop I read them and with definition an `IF` i chose the minimum one. that way is a little longer but more simpler

Comment: If `from scipy.optimize` you `import minimize as opt`, you should later call `opt(chisqfunc,x0)`. If instead you `import scipy.optimize as opt` you can call  `opt.minimize(chisqfunc,x0)`. This is about the error you get. For everything else, may I again remind you of [mcve] (what is `r` here, what is `am`? what is `v_obs`? etc..., just copy the code from your question, try to run it and if it produces the behaviour you want to ask about, it is a [mcve], else, it is not)